# how can i check duplicate value of a field into data base and show validation on it

Tags: java

```
String un = store.getSms();
String sql = "SELECT SMS FROM MYDB WHERE SMS_ = '" +cn+"'";

prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
int count = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    count = count + 1;
}

if (count > 1) {
    infoIsValid = false;
    errorMessage = errorMessage.concat("Duplicate keyword Found. Please create new sms" + "\n");
} else {
    insert query
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code is OK, then what is wrong with the result?

Comment: you can construct your query similar to something like this..SELECT my_column, COUNT(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_column
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: Your query is still vulnerable to SQL injection, considering that you're still building out a concatenated query *before* preparing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking the wrong question of the database.  You want the count of rows that match the condition, so you should ask for that instead.

Note that the below is untested, and since I don't know the *exact* type of `cn`, I'm assuming that it's a `String` of some kind.

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYDB WHERE SMS_ = ?";
prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStmt.setString(1, cn);
rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.hasNext()) {
    int count = rs.getInt();
    // validation logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in SQL query itself - 
Please see the below example for the same -

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Use group on the column for which you want to find the duplicate value.

Note: the ANSI standard is to have all non aggregated columns in the GROUP BY.

Comment: The question wasn't how to do it with SQL.  It's how to do it with SQL *through* Java.  This will absolutely work, but it's not answering the right question.